# how to pass string with / or any other special character using javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I am calling one javascript function like

```
echo "<td name='patient' width='60px' class='filter' Onclick='patient($id,$pid,$sid);return false;' ><a  >".$pid."</a></td>";
```

Here pid is like 242 or 243/3 or 243@3.

if it is a number its working pefect.

But with special character it is not working

Any help?

Comment: what kind of type do you want them to be in the javascript? Numbers? Strings?

Comment: @Xymostech it comes from database. am unable to confirm at particular

Comment: @Tushar its not working.

Comment: @jaya do `console.log` inside your javascript function and see what it's getting?

Comment: patient(\"$id",\"$pid\",\"$sid\") perhaps

Comment: @Tushar link was like this patientdetails.php?cid=43&pid=0.006625891946992864&sid=37463  for pid= 13/01962

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
echo "<td name='patient' width='60px' class='filter'>";
echo "<a href='#' onclick='patient(\"".$id."\",\"".$pid."\",\"".$sid."\");return false;'>".$pid."</a></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use    `escape(variable name)` in javascript function